Solaris 10: usb disk is see..but format?
Solaris 10: the command cfgadm show the disk
cfgadm -al usb3/1
Ap_Id                          Type         Receptacle   Occupant     Condition
usb3/1                         usb-storage  connected    configured   ok

also report info
usb3/1                         connected    configured   ok         Mfg: QEMU  Product: QEMU USB HARDDRIVE  NConfigs: 1  Config: 0  : High speed config (usb 2.0)
unavailable  usb-storage  n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci1af4,1100@4,7:1

format don't see it
sudo format
Searching for disks...done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0t1d0 <ATA    -QEMU HARDDISK  -2.5+ cyl 7829 alt 2 hd 255 sec 63>
          /pci@0,0/pci1af4,1100@5/disk@1,0
Specify disk (enter its number): 

How to get the disk available?
EDIT1: the command rmformat see the disk but cannot format/partition it

Solution found: a better solution was to remove the usb disk under the control of volfs (ignore the volume or something) but this workaround works fine also.
a)format don't see the disk
sudo format
Searching for disks...done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0t1d0 <ATA    -QEMU HARDDISK  -2.5+ cyl 7829 alt 2 hd 255 sec 63>
          /pci@0,0/pci1af4,1100@5/disk@1,0
Specify disk (enter its number): 

b) disable temporary the volfs daemon
sudo svcadm disable -t svc:/system/filesystem/volfs:default

c)now format can see it, I select to use it as ufs fs
so I run fdisk, part, and finally label within the format command.
sudo format -e
Searching for disks...done

selecting c1t0d0
[disk formatted]....

c)create an ufs fs
sudo newfs /dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s0    
newfs: construct a new file system /dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s0: (y/n)? y
Warning: 5008 sector(s) in last cylinder unallocated
/dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s0:     39857264 sectors in 6488 cylinders of 48 tracks, 128 sectors
        19461.6MB in 406 cyl groups (16 c/g, 48.00MB/g, 5824 i/g)
super-block backups (for fsck -F ufs -o b=#) at:
 32, 98464, 196896, 295328, 393760, 492192, 590624, 689056, 787488, 885920,
Initializing cylinder groups:
.......
super-block backups for last 10 cylinder groups at:
 38929952, 39028384, 39126816, 39225248, 39323680, 39422112, 39520544,
 39618976, 39717408, 39815840

d)re-enable volfs
sudo svcadm enable svc:/system/filesystem/volfs:default        

e)the disk is under /rmdisk/unnamed_rmdisk/s0
gdf -hT /rmdisk/unnamed_rmdisk/s0
Filesystem                            Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/vol/dev/dsk/c1t0d0/unnamed_rmdisk/s0 ufs    19G   20M   19G   1% /rmdisk/unnamed_rmdisk/s0

f)for zfs (works also for ufs) I have removed the reference of c1t0d0 and rmdisk from vold.conf
stop temporary vold, create zfs fs, reboot and all works fine
